# Determining proper decoding technique

Tags: encoding, base64, decode, mime, geocaching

I am trying to figure out how to decode this string as part of a geocaching puzzle:

4vU8XHh8AQobJTyGY0dluvecMvMVHbf0JLfZTB8komg=

I thought it might be MIME encoded but I cannot find a decoder that gives me any useful information.

Answer (score 0):

The data is quite clearly [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) (the restricted character repertoire could otherwise be pretty much anything, but the final `=` is not used elsewhere in base64 which is IMHO a giveaway; it is used to pad the end of the string so that it is always a multiple of four characters long) but decoding it doesn't reveal anything useful at least to me.

```
bash-3.2@osx-yosemite$ base64 -D <<<'4vU8XHh8AQobJTyGY0dluvecMvMVHbf0JLfZTB8komg=' |
> xxd
0000000: e2f5 3c5c 787c 010a 1b25 3c86 6347 65ba  ..<\x|...%<.cGe.
0000010: f79c 32f3 151d b7f4 24b7 d94c 1f24 a268  ..2.....$..L.$.h
```